# Data shows in BIDS preview but won't load when running

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids, interbase, dataflow

Fairly new to SSIS and having a problem with one table on my raw and history loads. Loading from an interbase table to a SQL server 2008 R2 via SSIS. In BIDS I can preview the table and it shows data, but when I run the data flow task nothing loads in AND doesn't give me any error messages, it says it successfully runs. Other tables from that database load fine. Anyone have any ideas? I can provide additional details if necessary

Comment: Do you have a parameter or some other filter applied to the source data during execution? Does the data flow provide opportunities for source rows to not arrive at the destination (conditional split, lookups, merge joins, etc)?

Comment: It has a couple splits but I put a data viewer between the data source and the first conversion task (like convert to unicode) and it's not even getting there.   To my knowledge there isn't any parameters or filters applied to the source data, it just stopped loading one day. I thought maybe it was a problem with the triggers but even the full history load has that problem.

Comment: Turns out it was a probably with the environment, got it working now. Thanks for all your help!